# jQuery .click(): get attribute from DIVs with the same class

Tags: jquery, html, click, attr

I have a problem with click event; here's the code:

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.myClass').click(function() {
        alert($(.myClass).attr("iditem"));
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="myClass" iditem="1">
    1 
</div>
<div class="myClass" iditem="2">
    2
</div>
```

Two `DIV` with same class, but different values for the same attribute, when I click on a `DIV`, alert print always "1" (it seems ignoring the declaration of second `DIV`). Why `.attr()` doesn't take the right value for the second `DIV`?

Comment: missing quotes, else use a "this"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you have `$('.myClass').attr("iditem")`, this will always return the attribute of the **first** element in the set, as described in the [documentation  *<sup>[docs] þ</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

> Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements.

So instead of selecting **all** elements with class `myClass` (that's what `$('.myClass')` does, no matter where/when it is called), you want to get a reference to the clicked element. Simply do:

```
$(this).attr('iditem');
```

`this` always refers to the element the event handler was bound to.

I suggest to use HTML5 [`data-*` attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) instead of custom attributes, to have at least valid HTML5:

```
 <div class="myClass" data-item="1">
```

You can then use [`.data()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to retrieve the value.

---

þ: You really should read jQuery's documentation. It provides many examples and a detailed description of how each method works. Make sure you also understand how [selectors *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) work.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to show the itemid of the item you click on? Then, this works:

```
$('.myClass').click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr("iditem"));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`alert($(".myClass").attr("iditem"));`

Answer (score 0):

`$(".myClass")` returns all elements with the class `myClass`. I think you want something like this instead:

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('.myClass').click(function() {
            alert($(this).attr("iditem"));
        });
    });
```